# Hi im new in wordpress and i need to know how to create a snippet

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets, yoast

Im Trying to create a snippet for a landing page but i need the url of the snippet have a anchor and direct me to an exact point of the web page.

this is the Url [image]

[image]

[image]

Maybe do you know how can create a specific slug with a anchor???

Comment: This question seems to be about the Yoast SEO plugin. You should ask your question to their support team or on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: Questions about plugins are off topic there.